# How to print database names and their collections names in order using nodeJS MongoClient?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to print list of database names following their corresponding collection names using a nested loop with MongoDB Node.js Driver.

**Database A:**
Collection a
Collection b
**Database B:**
Collection f
Collection g
**Database C:**
Collection h
Collection j

but instead I get this:
**Database A:**
**Database B:**
**Database C:**
Collection a
Collection b
Collection f
Collection g
Collection h
Collection j

What am I doing wrong? Is this because `listDatabases()` and `listCollections()` sharing the same MongoClient connection and they can't be executed simultaneously or it is just `promise` thing?

```
const mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017';

mongo.connect(url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}, (err, client) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return;
    }
    // print db names with their corresponding collections
    client.db().admin().listDatabases({ nameOnly: true }, (err, result) => {
        if (!err) {
            result.databases.forEach((db) => {
                console.log('Database: ' + db.name);

                client.db(db.name).listCollections().toArray((err, collections) => {
                    collections.forEach((col) => {
                        console.log(col.name);
                    });
                });

            });
        } else {
            return console.log(err.message);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `dbName` is an optional parameter of db(). From the [documentations](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/MongoClient.html#db)

Comment: Yes! Just an FYI with `mongodb@3.3.1` (which i was on) this was not the case but with `V3.3.3` latest as of now `dbName` optionality is working indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because **`client.db(db.name).listCollections()`** is `async` operation. To put it very plainly the `result.databases.forEach` is not going to wait for each listing of collections for the current db that just got printed above. Which is evident from the output.

That is how callbacks with `async` operations behave. This could be made nicer to look with **`async/await`** or **`promise/then`** syntaxes. If sticking to callback syntax, simply moving console of db inside would achieve the output.

```
// print db names with their corresponding collections
client
  .db("test")
  .admin()
  .listDatabases({ nameOnly: true }, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.error("Error::", err.message);
    }
    results.databases.forEach((item, index) => {
      client
        .db(item.name)
        .listCollections()
        .toArray((err, collections) => {
          if (err) {
            return console.error("Error::", err.message);
          }
          console.info("DATABASE: ", item.name);
          collections.forEach(col => {
            console.info("COLLECTION: ", col.name);
          });
        });
    });
  });
```

**UPDATE: With `async/await` syntax**

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
const client = new MongoClient(url, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});
const defaultDb = "test";

(async function() {
  try {
    await client.connect();
    //fetching dbs
    const dbs = await client
      .db(defaultDb)
      .admin()
      .listDatabases({ nameOnly: true });

    for (db of dbs.databases) {
      console.info("Database::", db.name);
      const collections = await client
        .db(db.name)
        .listCollections()
        .toArray();

      for (c of collections) {
        console.info("Collection::", c.name);
      }
    }
    client.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.stack);
  }
})();
```

Notice the `for..of` syntax with `await` because `forEach` doesn't behave the way intended [Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop?rq=1). And a plain `for(let i=0 ... i++)` would also work just fine with `await`.

Answer (score 1):

try to convert it to promise and use the map to async await the results 
thus https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-async-await-array-map/ may be helpfull

Comment: Convert what..?

Comment: I am soory It was not clear. get a list of databases and save it in array. and then loop over them using map to get their collections. you need to use async/await in map so ckeck the link